# Customizing li length of Boostrap dropdown-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I want to customize the length of `li` element/tag(of `Boostrap` dropdown-menu) to be of mininum length `200 px`.

Can somebody help me on which syntax to use?

I am looking in Bootstrap css file, and cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the bootstrap.css is not such a good idea. When you need to update you bootstrap library, you will need to keep track of all the changes you have made.
If you want to customize your HTLM bootstrap elements, it is better to create a new `.css` with all your custom styling.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- make sure to add you custom.css after bootstrap.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"> 
</head>
```

And now in your custom css you can customize you components

```
li{
  width: 200px;
}
```

In addition to make it easier to keep track of you custom changes, all your changes will be intact after future upgrades.

Comment: Hello, I'm not fool to make changes in Boostrap.css :) I was just looking in in to track what element to change in custom css. Unfortunately .li is not changing with your code, I tried the same yesterday.

Comment: Just realized I made a small error. Try `li` instead of `.li` to select the element, not the class. Updated my answer.

Comment: Anyway is not working, maybe li is getting the width of parent element. I can not figure it out.